# Make a GET-request to an endpoint API and use data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a `GET` from an API using Axios, but I'm doing something wrong.

#### Applications.tsx

```
import { getEntities, getFilteredEntities, getIntegrations } from './apps.reducer';

useEffect(() => {
    sortEntities();
    props.getIntegrationLevels();
    props.getEntitiesRealm();
  }, [paginationState.activePage, paginationState.order, paginationState.sort]);

//........

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getEntities,
  getEntitiesRealm,
  getFilteredEntities,
  getIntegrations,
};
```

In my reducer.ts page:

```
export const getIntegrations: ICrudGetAllAction<any> = (page, size, sort) => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrlIntegration}${sort ? `?page=${page}&size=${size}&sort=${sort}` : ''}`;
  return{
    type: "FETCH_GET",
    payload: axios.get<any>(`${requestUrl}${sort ? '&' : '?'}cacheBuster=${new Date().getTime()}`),
  };
}
```

Now if I see the network (on my browser), the call works and I have results, but I don't know how to use this data.

EDIT:

I have tried like this:

```
export const getIntegrationLevels = async (page, size, sort) => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrlIntegration}${sort ? `?page=${page}&size=${size}&sort=${sort}` : ''}`;
  try{
    const resp = await  axios.get<any>(`${requestUrl}${sort ? '&' : '?'}cacheBuster=${new Date().getTime()}`)
    console.log("resp ", resp)
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

but I receive error: `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Comment: You should wait for the axios response with the data ready and then move forward returning the {type, payload} where payload is the response data you got from api call. 

try `async await`

Comment: @kunalpanchal I should move the return??

Comment: you can just call axios before returning Object so that you can then return the Object when you get the api response.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called:

**#### Async Logic and Data Fetching**
Whenever an action is doing something `async` like calling http endpoint, you need to use a middleware for redux like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`.

In normal redux the data flow is

```
Action => Reducer => State => UI
```

when having an `async` action the flow changes to [image: From redux docs]

Read and apply the knowledge at their [documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic) to solve this problem